# Can two closed strings in string theory be tangled?

Tags: string-theory

Can two closed strings in string theory be tangled? Like two elements in an iron chain linked together by one going through the other.

Comment: Using a classical analogy like that **may** yield a misconception(namely that strings can behave like that, which seems intuitive. However very little is intuitive at the Planck scale) but a similar question that is **potentially** more viable is "can two closed strings merge?" Open strings on same orientation within a D25 brane can merge to form a closed string, but I don't know the probability of the "iron chain" arising if four strings merged simultaneously.